# groupby query elasticsearch with given parameters

Tags: elasticsearch

I run a query that find documents math with given ip's and groupy them by ip each group should contain category,clientip,and respsize
"url": "http://pancake.apple.com/cmremoteconfig/2/default",

```
           "clientmac": "ac:7f:3e:27:24:fc",
           "hierarchycode": "HIER_DIRECT/23.221.173.39",
           "user": "-",
           "duration": "129",
           "respsize": "2821",
           "clientip": "192.168.5.70",
           "loggingdate": "04/11/2015 07:26:20",
           "resultcode": "TCP_MISS/200",
           "reqmethod": "GET",
           "category": "11",
           "clientname": "192.168.5.70"
```

what I try:

```
POST webproxylog/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "filtered":{  
         "filter":{  
            "bool":{  
               "must":[  
                  {  
                     "terms":{  
                        "clientip":[  
                           "192.168.5.84",
                           "192.157.5.101"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "categories":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"category",
            "size":9999,
            "order":{  
               "sum_respsize":"desc"
            }
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "sum_respsize":{  
               "sum":{  
                  "field":"respsize"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

it returns:

```
"buckets": [
            {
               "key": "11",
               "doc_count": 2080,
               "sum_respsize": {
                  "value": 959711609
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "27",
               "doc_count": 1458,
               "sum_respsize": {
                  "value": 25747310
               }
            },...
```

Actually its close I need; I want these buckets contains each given clientname as parameter. like this

```
"buckets": [
                {
                   "key": "11",
                   "clientip":"192.168.5.101"
                   "doc_count": 2080,
                   "sum_respsize": {
                      "value": 959711609
                   }
                },
                {
                   "key": "27",
                   "clientip":"192.168.5.84"
                   "doc_count": 1458,
                   "sum_respsize": {
                      "value": 25747310
                   }
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "clientip": [
                  "192.168.5.84",
                  "192.157.5.101"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category",
        "size": 9999,
        "order": {
          "sum_respsize": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_respsize": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "respsize"
          }
        },
        "ip_top_tags": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "include": "clientip"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```